# Google maps api Geocoding service form

Tags: php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mysqli

I have a database with clients names and address, i am trying to display a map depending on their address. I have looked at the google api samples and decided I would use the *Geocoding service api.*

As you can see by the code below there is a form, Instead of the form I am wanting to make it automatically update when loaded as i will change the value with data from my database.

the form

```
<div id="panel">
          <input id="address" type="textbox" value="littleport">
          <input type="button" value="update" onclick="codeAddress()">
        </div>
```

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>


#map-canvas, #map_canvas {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map-canvas, #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="littleport">
      <input type="button" value="update" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can this be done?

here is the form

```
<div id="panel">
          <input id="address" type="textbox" value="<?php echo$address; ?>">
          <input type="button" value="update" onclick="codeAddress()">
        </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `automatically update when loaded as i will change the value with data from my database.`? Isn't that what the `<?php echo$address; ?>` does?

Comment: yes it does but i am wanting it to display the location with out me having to click the button to show the location

Comment: calling codeAddress() at the end of your initialization routine doesn't do that?